# php general question

Tags: php, variables, formatting

Hey i was looking through some of WP's code and I noticed in certain cases between double quotes, they put curly brackets around the variable. Here is an example:

```
$templates[] = "header-{$name}.php";
```

I tried looking online, but found it difficult to search for this. Would anyone be able to explain the use of this / benefits?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double

Scroll way down to the part on variable parsing for a detailed explanation.

Basically, inside a double-quoted string, PHP with replace variables with their contents.

```
$var = 'pig';
echo "Hello, $var"; // echos Hello, pig
```

Wrapping the variable in curly braces allows you to access associative arrays, object members, functions, etc (`"{$var['key']} {$foo->bar} {${$foo->baz()}}"`), and makes your code a little more readable (imho)

Answer (score 0):

It mainly allows you to specify things like arrays.  An example would be:

```
$arr = array("mon"=>"Monday","tue"=>"Tuesday");
echo "Today is {$arr["mon"]}";
```

It has its place, but doesn't need to be used with the example above.  Some people prefer it (to help them tell the variables from the string), and some prefer to just use single quotes with concatenation.